# Windows-1252 (80-9F) control characters are inserted as � in oracle db when it is inserted from sqlplus in linux server

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, control-characters

When I insert the Windows-1252 (80-9F) control characters from sql developer in windows, they get inserted correctly into oracle db.

But when I use `sqlplus` in linux server, the  control characters are inserted as � in same db.

For example, when I execute below statement in linux server sqlplus,

```
insert into demo values ('“a”');
```

I get the below output inserted in db:

�a�

Samething happens for other control characters like `Œ, Ž, Š, ‹`, etc..

My locale setting:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: encoding issue perhaps?

Comment: Do you have a `NLS_LANG` env variable?

Comment: I have LANG env var. LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Linux box is using UTF-8 (`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`) so you need to tell SQL*Plus that everything you type is using that encoding. The way to do so ([the only way to do so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36170/set-encoding-from-within-sqlplus), as far as I know) is to create the `NLS_LANG` env variable and asign it the Oracle code for UTF-8—I've found two different values in the docs I've googled into:

```
NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
```

The [Oracle Database Client Globalization Support](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B13804_02/gblsupp.htm#BCEEEJGF) doesn't shed much light on the subject but I've always used `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`.

Comment: After setting NLS_LANG, Need to change in putty Settings/Window/Translation: Remote character set should be UTF-8. Now it worked.